# ionic2: dynamically append or set ion-input name?

Tags: angular, ionic2

i want to add a copy, like this.

```
<button ion-button="addFriend()">add</button>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="friend[0]" type="text">Friend</ion-input>
```

after called addFriend()

```
<button ion-button="addFriend()">add</button>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="friend[0]" type="text">Friend</ion-input>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="friend[1]" type="text">Friend</ion-input>
```

and i tried set ion-input name, like this.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="data">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of data.column">
      <ion-label class="column-label" wrap>{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="columnId[{{column.cid}}]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 'text' || column.columnType == 'tel'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

but throw errors...

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input [ERROR ->]name="columnId[{{column.cid}}]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == "): TablePage@18:17 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input [ERROR ->]name="columnId[{{column.cid}}]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == "): TablePage@18:17
    at TemplateParser.parse (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js:131:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:282:51)
    at eval (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:83)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:47)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
    at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11411) Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input [ERROR ->]name="columnId[{{column.cid}}]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == "): TablePage@18:17
    at TemplateParser.parse (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js:131:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:282:51)
    at eval (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:83)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:47)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
    at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
    at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11411)
```

Comment: what error are you getting? and what do you do in addFriend?

Comment: addFriend to do one thing, append <ion-input [(ngModel)]="friend[1]" type="text">Friend</ion-input> after <ion-input [(ngModel)]="friend[0]" type="text">Friend</ion-input>

Comment: so ion-input is in ngFor and friend is a string array?

Comment: if you repeat click addFriend, could be append more than input

Comment: how are you appending ion-input? *ngFor?

Comment: this is two case, i have edited the question, plz read again...

Answer (score 3):

```
<ion-list *ngIf="data">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of data.column">
      <ion-label class="column-label" wrap>{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input [name]="'columnId['+column.cid+']'" [type]="column.columnType" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 'text' || column.columnType == 'tel'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Binding to the `name` and `type` with a variable created with angular or typescript, you'll have to use `[name]` and `[type]`.

This will output:

`<ion-input name="columnId[9]" type="text" clearOnEdit>`

Also see this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/tAQrHQHpNj8RvymxOBkF?p=preview

*unless you want to use the value of an array called `columnId`*

Comment: A bit more info than "it's not work" would allow me to help you further. Any error messages for example?

Answer (score 0):

{{}} is not used for attributes.
Try this -

```
<ion-list *ngIf="data">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of data.column">
      <ion-label class="column-label" wrap>{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="columnId[column.cid]" type="column.columnType" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 'text' || column.columnType == 'tel'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list *ngIf="data">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of data.column">
      <ion-label class="column-label" wrap>{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="columnId[column.cid]" type="column.columnType" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 'text' || column.columnType == 'tel'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

throw error

```
 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
    1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input [ERROR ->][name]="columnId[column.cid]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 't"): TablePage@18:17 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
    1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input [ERROR ->][name]="columnId[column.cid]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 't"): TablePage@18:17
        at TemplateParser.parse (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js:131:19)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:282:51)
        at eval (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:83)
        at Set.forEach (native)
        at compile (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:47)
        at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
        at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
        at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
        at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11411) Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
    1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input [ERROR ->][name]="columnId[column.cid]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 't"): TablePage@18:17
        at TemplateParser.parse (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js:131:19)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:282:51)
        at eval (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:83)
        at Set.forEach (native)
        at compile (/Users/vancy/ionic/tongzhanbu/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:187:47)
        at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13422)
        at e.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10809)
        at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8911
        at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14051)
        at e.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11411)
    o @ polyfills.js:3
    r @ polyfills.js:3
    i @ polyfills.js:3
    polyfills.js:3 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
    1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'name' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("l" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input [ERROR ->][name]="columnId[column.cid]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 't"): TablePage@18:17
        at s (polyfills.js:3)
        at s (polyfills.js:3)
        at polyfills.js:3
        at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at e.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
        at i (polyfills.js:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let column of data.column">
      <ion-label class="column-label" wrap *ngIf="column.columnType != 'tableLine'">{{column.columnName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="columnId[column.cid]" type="{{column.columnType}}" clearOnEdit *ngIf="column.columnType == 'text' || column.columnType == 'tel'"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

output

```
<ion-input clearonedit="" name="columnId[column.cid]" class="input input-ios" ng-reflect-type="text">
<input class="text-input text-input-ios ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" clearonedit="" name="columnId[column.cid]" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" ng-reflect-klass="text-input" ng-reflect-ng-class="text-input-ios" ng-reflect-type="text" type="text" placeholder="">
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><button class="text-input-clear-icon disable-hover button button-ios button-clear button-clear-ios" clear="" ion-button="" type="button" ng-reflect-hidden="true" hidden=""><span class="button-inner"></span><div class="button-effect"></div></button><!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
</ion-input>
```

Comment: is columnId array set in class?

Comment: no...columnId not is a class member, it's formdata name.

Comment: what?? do you know what formdata?

Comment: I didnt get you. u r using reactive form? formControl?

Comment: no, name is array...then server will get value like this.---- column[] = [a, b, c] ----

Comment: you have name=columnId[0] .. column is the data.column.. there is no columnId

Comment: <form><input name="columnId[999]"><input name="columnId[888]"></form>..this is no problem...

Comment: column is the data.column,but  columnId is attr.name... e.x.  data.column.cid=100, then  <input name="columnId[100]" />